# Geometry analogy, why don't I get more answer?

Tags: prolog

Here is my prolog code :

```
figure(1, middle(circle, circle)).
figure(2, top_left(circle, circle)).
figure(3, bottom_right(circle, circle)).
figure(4, middle(square, square)).
figure(5, top_left(square, square)).
figure(6, top_right(square, square)).
figure(7, bottom_right(square, square)).
figure(8, bottom_left(square, square)).

relate(F1, F2, Relation) :-
    (   figure(F1, middle(X, Y)),  figure(F2, middle(Y, X)), F1 \== F2 ->
        Relation = invert
    ;   figure(F1, middle(X, X)), figure(F2, middle(Y, Y)), F1 \== F2 ->
        Relation = same_in_out
    ;   figure(F1, top_left(X, X)), figure(F2, bottom_right(Y, Y)), F1 \== F2 ->
        Relation = opposite
    ;   figure(F1, top_right(X, X)), figure(F2, bottom_left(Y, Y)), F1 \== F2 ->
        Relation = opposite
    ;   relate(F2, F1, Relation)
    ).

analogy((F1, F2), (F3, X)) :-
    relate(F1, F2, Relation), relate(F3, X, Relation).
```

Which represent this set [image]

And here is a simple execution :

```
| ?- relate(2, X, Y).

X = 3
Y = opposite;

no
| ?- relate(2, 7, X).

X = opposite;

no
```

And my question is, why I don't have X = 7, Y = opposite, when I do relate(2, X, Y) ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you think of a title for your question that is more descriptive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you use if-then-else, and Prolog won't backtrack out of such a construct:

```
?- (member(X, [1,2,3]) -> Y = hello ; Y = goodbye).
X = 1,
Y = hello.

?-
```

If-then-else is really meant for efficient deterministic computation. You should rewrite your predicate using ordinary conjunction, disjunction and listings of facts if you want non-determinism/backtracking:

```
relate(F1, F2, Relation) :-
    figure(F1, Fig1),
    figure(F2, Fig2),
    relate_(Fig1, Fig2, Relation),
    F1 \== F2.

relate_(middle(X, Y), middle(Y, X), invert).
% etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to larsmans answer:

If your Prolog system has "soft cuts" (e.g., ECLiPSe, SWI-Prolog), then you can replace '->'/2 by '*->'/2, i.e.

```
figure(F1, top_left(X, X)), figure(F2, bottom_right(Y, Y)), F1 \== F2 ->
    Relation = opposite
```

is replaced by

```
figure(F1, top_left(X, X)), figure(F2, bottom_right(Y, Y)), F1 \== F2 *->
    Relation = opposite
```

If the condition suceeded, then the soft cut allows backtracking into the condition in order to return alternative solutions for the condition and the consequent. The alternative branch will never be executed if the condition succeeded. Only if the condition failed outright will the alternative branch be executed.